# How to find virtual machine throught windows

Tags: windows, file, virtual-machine, samba

I work with samba on my vm, I created directories and configured it,but when I go in my mainPc where vm installed,I cant find it throught windows,according to instroctions I have to put ip in next section with sleshes,but it does not worK:
Can you recomend some settings

[image]